# PHP & AJAX - No Refresh to Fetch data to another page and make it Modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have two browsers and im fetching data to the other browser, I've managed to fetch the data without refresh, but i want to make the data to be fetch in a `modal` and right now when i post data on the other page modal is not display. help please,

here is what i want please see this image

[image]

here is my **Ajax4.html**  - *left browser*

my ***button to insert data***

```
 <button type="submit"  value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">POST TO AJAX 5</button>
```

my ***Script***

```
   <script>
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', getName);

    document.getElementById('postForm').addEventListener('submit', postName);



    function postName(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var name = document.getElementById('name2').value;
      var params = "name="+name;

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'process.php', true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

      xhr.onload = function(){
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }

      xhr.send(params);
    }
  </script>
```

my ***Ajax5.html***

my `div` where the data will come out

```
<h1>Alert User</h1>
    <div id="users"></div>
```

my **script** - here is where the modal should be based and show.

```
<script>
var still_fetching = false;

//fetch data every 3 seconds (3000)
setInterval(function(){ 
     if (still_fetching) {
         return;
     }
     still_fetching = true;
     loadUsers();
}, 3000);

//need to update a bit this function
function loadUsers(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'users.php', true);

        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status == 200){
                var users = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                var output = '';

                for(var i in users){
                output +=  '<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">' +
                              '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">' +
                                '<div class="modal-content">' +
                                 ' <div class="modal-header">' +
                                  ' <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>' +
                                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">' +
                                     ' <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>' +
                                  '  </button>' +
                                 ' </div>' +
                                 ' <div class="modal-body">' +

                                  '<h5 class="card-title">' +users[i].id+ '</h5>' +
                                  '<p class="card-text">' +users[i].name +'  </p>' +

                                 ' </div>' +
                                 ' <div class="modal-footer">' +
                                  ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>' +
                                   ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>' +
                                  '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                              '</div>' +
                            '</div>';

                }

                document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = output;
                still_fetching = false;
            }
        }

        xhr.send();
  }

</script>
```

My `process.php` here is where i connect and get the data

```
   <?php
//Connect to a database
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ajaxtest');



echo 'Processing....';

//Check for POST variable

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    //echo 'GET: Your name is '. $_POST['name'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('$name')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
        echo 'User Added...';
    }else{
        echo 'ERROR: '.mysql_error($conn);
    }
}



//Check for GET variable

if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    echo 'GET: Your name is '. $_GET['name'];
}
```

my `users.php` here is where i connect the database

```
    <?php 

//Create Connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ajaxtest');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM users';

//Get Result
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

//Fetch Data
$users = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($users);
```

Comment: learn ajax technologies.using [ajax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/what_is_ajax.htm) asynchronous data without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.

Comment: i have ive watched the crash courses tho that's why im asking for help on this website.. ive watched and im asking .. that means i need more help.. im still learning tho